# Can any 3d depth camera such as Intels RealSenses work with Windows Hello facial verification system?

Tags: windows-10, windows-hello

I'm looking for webcams that work with Windows Hello Facial verification system. However, I cant simply find any that works well.

There are several webcams such as :

- [Logitec BRIO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N5UOYC4)
- [Creative-Blasterx](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J2SDB4M)
- [LilBit Face Recognition](https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=Kaysuda%20Face%20Recognition%20USB%20IR%20Camera%20for%20Windows%20Hello%20Windows%2010%20System,%20RGB%20720P%20Webcam%20with%20Dual%20Microphone%20for%20Streaming%20Video%20Conference%20and%20YouTube%20Recording%20for%20Windows&linkCode=gs3&linkId=ae772a7ff0be974ff3746aa0a2eb4012&tag=faceofitde02-21)
- [Mouse Facial Recognition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NRLB1QW)
- etc

that all stopped working in the latest windows 10 update (1909 it seems) and it seems these are pretty much the only models that are supposedly `Windows Hello certified!`
What is the requirements for Windows Hello Facial verification system ?
I want to find any webcam that can work, but I dont know what to search for or to look for in the webcam description!
Simply searching the `windows hello webcam` in amazon for example, doesnt provide any useful information as it will just list random webcams.
googling also doesnt help much either, as it just shows up pages where the aformentioned products + some others that are not clearly windows hello compliant are introduced!
So Should the webcam has both a near-infrared sensor and a 3d depth sensor in order to be able to be compliant with Windows Hello or a simple depth camera is enough? I'm asking  to see if I can find any webcam that has 3d depth and get it to work with windows hello.

Comment: Those cameras if they worked previously should still work with 1909 (the Windows Hello requirements certainly hasn’t been modified).  Suspect it stopped working for a different reason

Comment: This [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/windows-hello-biometric-requirements) indicates the Windows Hello Biometric requirements for a camera.  However, for the device to be eligible, they must be certified by Microsoft.  This would be a major selling point for a camera.  Specifications will specify this compatible

Comment: Thanks a lot. but there are lots of buyers in the comments section of those products that stated after the update those camers stopped working. I just found that Intels RealSense SR300 cameras do support Windows Hello! However, the driver is outdated and never updated since 2016! I believe lots of those webcasme use this module and thats why they all failed together! Also the latest series such as D400 do not support Windows Hello!

Comment: Also I couldnt find any hardware specified requirements in the page you kindly posted! where exactly are you refering in  that page?

Comment: The FAR and TAR percentages.  I wouldn’t expect the drivers to be updated.  Wouldn’t read into the fact the drivers are a few years old.

Comment: My web camera is one of those cameras you listed and it still works on my personal 1909 install

Comment: FAR and TAR are simply metrics used from the software point of view concerning the status of verification. they do not imply any hardware specificification such as what kind of infrared is needed, what spectrum is needed, whats the minimum and maximum depth is supported, etc .
Concerning the cameras, those webcams RGB camera still work just fine. however the depth part needed by the Hello system seem to be failing.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm in a similar situation...

Comment: No, not really as we didnt get realsense. If you have one you can give it a try. if you dont, get a certified webcam.

Answer (score 1):

Intels RealSense SR300 camera is working with Windows Hello running Windows 10 Pro version #1803. The facial recognition in "Sign-in options" did not succeed until after I opened and used the ZOOM App to select the realSense SR300 camera as the default video device in the App. I had this camera for a few years and just installed it for the first time during the COVID-19 stay-at-home order.